# change span icon when body rtl or ltr

Tags: html, css

I want to change span content with CSS when click on div . when body direction is `rtl`,span content must be `keyboard_arrow_left` and then `ltr` must span content be `keyboard_arrow_right` .

This is my HTML code :

```
<div class="inner-item">
  <div>
    <h2 class="title m-0">
      Security Setting
    </h2>
  </div>
  <span class="icon"></span>
</div>
```

I want when click on `inner-items` the span `.icon` change content .

```
 .inner-sidebar {
  .inner-item {
    &.active {
      color: #ff5722;
      .icon::after {
        font-family: "Material Icons";
        body[dir="rtl"] {
          content: "keyboard_arrow_left";
        }
        body[dir="ltr"] {
          content: "keyboard_arrow_right";
        }
      }
    }
}
```

but when i click on div it not change content .

**how can i solve this issue ??**

Comment: I think **s** missing in scss `inner-items` that is  `.inner-items{..} `

Comment: @RayeesAC still not solved

Comment: is there any jquery or javascript to add class active to `inner-item` when cliked. if not you can use `:active` instead of `.active`.

Comment: @RayeesAC when i use this code its worked but when i want to use direction of body its not worked : `&.active {
      color: #ff5722;
      .icon::after {
        font-family: "Material Icons";
          content: "keyboard_arrow_right";
      }
    }`

Comment: Your sass is incorrect. `body` is nested inside an `after` pseudo element which instead should be the first element in the hierarchy of your content. Also you have to detect the click somehow, yet you don't show us any JS/jQuery code. We can't reproduce the issue if you don't include your complete code.

Comment: can i use jquery?

Comment: @RayeesAC no just css

Answer (score 0):

```css
.inner-item.active {
  color: #ff5722;
}

.inner-item .icon:before {
  font-family: "Material Icons";
}

.icon-rtl,
.icon-ltr {
  display: none !important;
}

body[dir="rtl"] .icon-rtl {
  display: inline-block !important;
}

body[dir="ltr"] .icon-ltr {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body dir="rtl">
  <div class="inner-item">
    <div class="title m-0">Security Setting
      
      <span class="material-icons icon-ltr">keyboard_arrow_right</span><span class="material-icons icon-rtl">keyboard_arrow_left</span> 
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
<html>
```

You can try something like this, if this can help you. From the official site material icons, I can see we use, https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=keyboard_arrow_left&style=outline, below syntax to use icons. Refer that as well. if you have already a javascript logic, you can do the same with javascript as well. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the SCSS structure. The content property belongs to icon:after and not the body-tag.

```html
 .inner-sidebar {
  .inner-item {
    &.active {
      color: #ff5722;
      .icon::after {
        font-family: "Material Icons";
        content: "keyboard_arrow_right";
      }
    }
}


body[dir="rtl"] {
  .inner-item {
    &.active {
      color: #ff5722;
      
      .icon:after {
        content: "keyboard_arrow_left";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I think you get what i mean :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you want something like this :)

**SCSS code :**

```
.inner-item:active {
  color: #ff5722;
}
.inner-item .icon::after {
  font-family: "Material Icons";
}
body[dir="ltr"] .inner-item {
    &:active .icon::after {
       content: "keyboard_arrow_left";
    }
    .icon::after {
       content: "keyboard_arrow_right";
    }
}
body[dir="rtl"] .inner-item {
    &:active .icon::after {
       content: "keyboard_arrow_right";
    }
    .icon::after {
       content: "keyboard_arrow_left";
    }
}
```

### **LTR** - **Demo**

```css
.inner-item:active {
  color: #ff5722;
}
.inner-item .icon::after {
  font-family: "Material Icons";
}
body[dir="ltr"] .inner-item .icon::after {
  content: "keyboard_arrow_right";
}
body[dir="ltr"] .inner-item:active .icon::after {
  content: "keyboard_arrow_left";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<h2>LTR</h2>
<body dir="ltr">
  <div class="inner-item">
    <div>
      <h2 class="title m-0">
        Security Setting
      </h2>
    </div>
    <span class="icon"></span>
  </div>
</body>
```

### RTL-Demo

```css
.inner-item:active {
  color: #ff5722;
}
.inner-item .icon::after {
  font-family: "Material Icons";
}
body[dir="rtl"] .inner-item .icon::after {
  content: "keyboard_arrow_left";
}
body[dir="rtl"] .inner-item:active .icon::after {
  content: "keyboard_arrow_right";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<h2>RTL</h2>
<body dir="rtl">
  <div class="inner-item">
    <div>
      <h2 class="title m-0">
        Security Setting
      </h2>
    </div>
    <span class="icon"></span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you click the **Security Setting** text to change the icon

Comment: What is the issue?